# How to get multiple characters from a string

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to learn c++, and I was informed that this website is a great place to start getting involved in.

I was just wondering if it were possible to retrieve multiple characters from a string rather then repeating multiple lines of code.

```
string lname = "";
char l = lname.at(0);
char a = lname.at(1);
```

Comment: [std::string::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: Yet, this "website" requires you to do your own research, before asking a question. And you know, what's the first thing you need to check, if you wonder if certain class has some functionality? Its [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). Specifically, for your case, the [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method.

Answer (score 0):

A string is essentially a char array followed by a NULL character.

The [string class reference guide](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) will help you know what you can and cannot do with a string variable. You didn't provide enough details for us to thoroughly answer your question, but if you are looking for a [substring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/), try using the ".substr" function in the string class.

For instance:

string tempString = "Hello, my name is brw59";

// at character 7 (starts at 0) print two characters
cout << tempString.substr(7, 2); // output == "my"